# Batch-File to open and close programs

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking for a way that I can open and close more than one program in a batch-file. Let programs be named Program and Server. I need Server to start first, then I can run Program.  When I close Program I want Server to stop the .exe for Server is one level down. I also want to introduce a delay so Server has started and is running before Program starts. how do I do it?

Comment: you can use `start` to start a program. The method for delay depends on your OS. You can use `tasklist` to check for a running program and kill a program with `taskkill`. For syntax see `<command> /?` /e.g `start /?`

Comment: Consider using VBscript.  I think it has the WaitWindow function if your program creates a window object.  Or alternatively, AutoHotkey.

Comment: I edited your question so that the confusing P & S use names.  Please clarify your question where it says `"I want Sampson to stop the .exe for Sampson is one level down"` because that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Programme and Server would have worked better considering that's what there called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
set prog1="Pigeon"
start "" %prog1%
sampson
taskkill /im %prog1%
```

Comment: so replacing the names it just starts Pigeon and never starts Samson.

Comment: I got it to work kinda but the server does not close after I close the program I'm getting `access denied`

Comment: on a side note how do I log the cmd window so I can bug fix instead of cmd closeing supper fast?

Comment: add a **pause** on the last line